# Calling one function two time results in strange results in Python

Tags: python

In the following code, I call the Sort function two times with a different behavior but it returns the same results. In the advancedSort() function, I called Sort() function two times with different behavior (order) and saved each result in different lists but when I am printing the lists the results are the same!

```
def Sort(inputs, order = "ascending"):
    if order == "ascending":
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(inputs)):
                if inputs[i] > inputs[j]:
                    inputs[i], inputs[j] = inputs[j], inputs[i]
                    
    elif order == "decending":
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(inputs)):
                if inputs[i] < inputs[j]:
                    inputs[i], inputs[j] = inputs[j], inputs[i]
    
    else: 
        raise ValueError(order)
        
    return inputs
        


def advancedSort(inputList, inputOrder):
    if inputOrder == "ascending":
        newList = Sort(inputList, "ascending")
        return newList
    elif inputOrder == "decending":
        newList = Sort(inputList, "decending")
        return newList
    elif inputOrder == "both":
        newList1 = Sort(inputList, "ascending")
        newList2 = Sort(inputList, "decending")
        return newList1, newList2
    else:
        raise ValueError(order)
        
        


        
a = [1, 4, 7, 7, 0, 6, 4]
print(a)
b, c = advancedSort(a, "both")
print(b)
print(c)
```

Output is:

```
[1, 4, 7, 7, 0, 6, 4]
[7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0]
[7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

When `Sort()` runs the first time it'll change the list referenced by **a**.

When you run it a second time, it's not using the original list you've defined in the beginning, but one already modified by `Sort()`.

To address this you may use a shallow copy of the list:

```
        newList1 = Sort(inputList.copy(), "ascending")
        newList2 = Sort(inputList.copy(), "decending")
```

I used your code to print the memory address of each variable and their behavior in the routines:

```
def Sort(inputs, order = "ascending"):
    if order == "ascending":
        print(f"running the ascending routine with inputs = {inputs} ({hex(id(inputs))})")
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(inputs)):
                if inputs[i] > inputs[j]:
                    inputs[i], inputs[j] = inputs[j], inputs[i]
    elif order == "decending":
        print(f"""running the decending routine with inputs = {inputs} ({hex(id(inputs))})""")
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(inputs)):
                if inputs[i] < inputs[j]:
                    inputs[i], inputs[j] = inputs[j], inputs[i]
    else: 
        raise ValueError(order)
    return inputs

def advancedSort(inputList, inputOrder):
    if inputOrder == "ascending":
        newList = Sort(inputList, "ascending")
        return newList
    elif inputOrder == "decending":
        newList = Sort(inputList, "decending")
        return newList
    elif inputOrder == "both":
        newList1 = Sort(inputList, "ascending")
        newList2 = Sort(inputList, "decending")
        return newList1, newList2
    elif inputOrder == "shallow":
        newList1 = Sort(inputList.copy(), "ascending")
        newList2 = Sort(inputList.copy(), "decending")
        return newList1, newList2
    else:
        raise ValueError(order)

a = [1, 4, 7, 7, 0, 6, 4]
print(f"a = {a} ({hex(id(a))})")
print("\ntrying shallow mode")
b, c = advancedSort(a, "shallow")
print(f"b = {b} ({hex(id(b))})")
print(f"c = {c} ({hex(id(c))})")
print("\ntrying both mode")
d, e = advancedSort(a, "both")
print(f"a = {a} ({hex(id(a))})")
print(f"d = {d} ({hex(id(d))})")
print(f"e = {e} ({hex(id(e))})")
print("\nnow trying shallow mode again")
f, g = advancedSort(a, "shallow")
print(f"a = {a} ({hex(id(a))})")
print(f"f = {f} ({hex(id(f))})")
print(f"g = {g} ({hex(id(g))})")
```

Output:

```
a = [1, 4, 7, 7, 0, 6, 4] (0x7f4166c71240)

trying shallow mode
running the ascending routine with inputs = [1, 4, 7, 7, 0, 6, 4] (0x7f4166a535c0)
running the decending routine with inputs = [1, 4, 7, 7, 0, 6, 4] (0x7f4166ac8a80)
b = [0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7] (0x7f4166a535c0)
c = [7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] (0x7f4166ac8a80)

trying both mode
running the ascending routine with inputs = [1, 4, 7, 7, 0, 6, 4] (0x7f4166c71240)
running the decending routine with inputs = [0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7] (0x7f4166c71240)
a = [7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] (0x7f4166c71240)
d = [7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] (0x7f4166c71240)
e = [7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] (0x7f4166c71240)

now trying shallow mode again
running the ascending routine with inputs = [7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] (0x7f4166ac88c0)
running the decending routine with inputs = [7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] (0x7f4166ac8780)
a = [7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] (0x7f4166c71240)
f = [0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7] (0x7f4166ac88c0)
g = [7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] (0x7f4166ac8780)
```

Comment: Adding `inputs = inputs.copy()` as the first line of the `Sort()` function provides the desired functionality without having to remember to pass a copy every time to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I made it that way just to show the difference, to help the OP see what's going on

Comment: oh! I just programmed in c++ and it was the first time that I am using Python. So it seems Python passes the variable to function by reference, not by value, am I right?

Comment: @Ali well, it depends on the context. A proper full explanation would make for a new SO question, but the thing that determines you must shallow copy the list here it's because you're using the same reference more than once and expecting it to be immutable. So the solution I proposed is the way to "fix" the code the way it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is because your function `Sort` (by the way it is better to rename it with lowercase `sort()`) it is changing the value of the original list. So, when you call with `"ascending"` or `"descending"`, there's no problem becuse you only order one time, but with `"both"` the `newList2 = Sort(inputList, "decending")` use an `a` list mutated.

**You never must work with the original list, always clone it and make the changes in the clone it**. To work:

```
def Sort(inputs, order = "ascending"):
    cloned_list = inputs[:]
    if order == "ascending":
        for i in range(len(cloned_list)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(cloned_list)):
                if cloned_list[i] > cloned_list[j]:
                    cloned_list[i], cloned_list[j] = cloned_list[j], cloned_list[i]
    elif order == "decending":
        for i in range(len(cloned_list)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(cloned_list)):
                if cloned_list[i] < cloned_list[j]:
                    cloned_list[i], cloned_list[j] = cloned_list[j], cloned_list[i]
    else: 
        raise ValueError(order)
    return cloned_list
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 7, 7, 0, 6, 4] # a
[0, 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7] # b 
[7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 1, 0] # c
```

Comment: Renaming it to lower case `sort()` would overwrite the built in method, which is definitely NOT recommended.